# Using ready paramiko connection

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Imagine a situation when two servers are available. One of them is constantly sshing to another one and executing some commands. The process takes around 5-10 seconds for each session since ssh connection must be established every time.

The question: is it possible to have a ready, established ssh connection in order to reduce the time of executing commands on remote server?

Comment: you may want to check [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/79645/ssh-run-a-command-on-login-and-then-stay-logged-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for you. It can work as a ssh client. No need to recreate session everytime.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-


import os,sys  
import paramiko    
import threading    
import platform  

curr_ssh = None   
curr_prompt = ">>"  

#how to use it    
def printUsage():  
    print "    !ls                     :list sessions."  
    print "    !session id             :connect session."  
    print "    !conn host user password:connect host with user."  
    print "    !exit                   :exit."  

#connect using paramiko   
def conn(ip,username,passwd):  
    try:  
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()    
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())    
        ssh.connect(ip,22,username,passwd,timeout=5)    
        print "Connect to ",ip," with ",username  
        global curr_prompt  
        curr_prompt=username+"@"+ip+">>"  
        return ssh  
    except:  
        return None  

#get former session
sessions=[]  
def loadSessions():  
    global sessions  
    try:  
        f = open("sessions")  
        sessions = f.readlines()  
        f.close()  
    except:  
        pass  

#main function   
def exe_cmd_local(cmd):  
    if(cmd == "!ls"):  
        loadSessions()  
        global sessions  
        i=0  
        print "Sessions:"  
        for s in sessions:  
            print"[%d] %s" %(i,s)  
            i+=1  
    else:  
        vals = cmd.split(' ')  
        if(vals[0]=="!session"):  
            id = (int)(vals[1])  
            if(id<len(sessions)):  
                os_name = platform.system()  

                new_console_cmd = ""  
                if(os_name == "Linux"):  
                    new_console_cmd="gnome-terminal -e \"./ssh.py " + sessions[id]+"\""  
                elif(os_name == "Windows"):  
                    new_console_cmd="start ssh.py " + sessions[id]  
                os.system(new_console_cmd)  
            else:  
                print "Didn't hava sessoin ",vals[1]  
        elif(vals[0]=="!conn"):  
            global curr_ssh  
            curr_ssh = conn(vals[1],vals[2],vals[3])  
            f = open("sessions","a")  
            line = vals[1]+" "+vals[2]+" "+vals[3]+"\n"  
            f.write(line)  
            f.close()  

#execute command remotely    
def exe_cmd_ssh(ssh,cmd):  
    if(ssh == None):  
        print "Didn't connect to a server. Use '!conn' to connect please."  
        return  
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)    
    print stdout.read()  
    print stderr.read()  

if __name__=='__main__':  
    loadSessions()  
    if(len(sys.argv)==4):  
        curr_ssh = conn(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3])  
    else:  
        printUsage()  
    while True:  
        cmd = raw_input(curr_prompt)  
        if(len(cmd)==0):  
            continue  

        if(cmd == "!exit"):  
            if(curr_ssh != None):  
                curr_ssh.close();  
            break  
        else:  
            if(cmd[0] == '!'):  
                exe_cmd_local(cmd)  
            else:  
                exe_cmd_ssh(curr_ssh,cmd)
```

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

One could use an existing ssh connection, by configuring ssh to re-use an already established connection. Please see man ssh_config:

```
 ControlMaster
         Enables the sharing of multiple sessions over a single network connection.  When set to “yes”, ssh(1) will ...
```

So your ~/.ssh/config could contain:

```
Host firstServer
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath  ~/.ssh/tmp/controlPath_%h_%p_%r
```

This will create a socket as a file named by 'ControlPath'. The next ssh connection will go through that same socket and will be lightning fast.

Enjoy